# R function to extract exact match

Tags: r

I have a table with some values combined, I'm trying to spread out the values:

```
ROLENAME                         Chairman Vice_Chairman Independent_Vice_Chairman CEO  President
CEO/Vice Chairman                    No        Yes               No                 Yes     No
Independent Vice Chairman            No         No               Yes                No      No
Chairman/President/CEO               Yes        No               No                 Yes     Yes
```

I tried using `if_else(str_detect(ROLENAME, "Chairman"),"Yes","No"))`, but this gives me all the values which has Chairman in it.

Is there a function that I can do exact match to get only Chairmen and not Vice Chairmen and Independent Vice chairmen?

Comment: maybe: `str_subset(ROLENAME, "^(?!Vice)Chairman")`

Comment: Thank you very much, this works!!